# How should I solve logic error in timestamp using Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have written a code to calculate `a`, `b`, and `c`. They were initialized at 0.
This is my input file

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| Line          | Time |     Command    |      Data         |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 1             | 0015 | ACTIVE         |                   |
| 2             | 0030 | WRITING        |                   |
| 3             | 0100 | WRITING_A      |                   |
| 4             | 0115 | PRECHARGE      |                   |
| 5             | 0120 | REFRESH        |                   |
| 6             | 0150 | ACTIVE         |                   |
| 7             | 0200 | WRITING        |                   |
| 8             | 0314 | PRECHARGE      |                   |
| 9             | 0318 | ACTIVE         |                   |
| 10            | 0345 | WRITING_A      |                   |
| 11            | 0430 | WRITING_A      |                   |
| 12            | 0447 | WRITING        |                   |
| 13            | 0503 | WRITING        |                   |
```

and the `timestamps` and `commands` are used to process the calculation for `a`, `b`, and `c`.

```
import re
count = {}
timestamps = {}
with open ("page_stats.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.split(r"\s*\|\s*", line)
        if len(m) > 3 and re.match(r"\d+", m[1]):
            count[m[3]] = count[m[3]] + 1 if m[3] in count else 1
            #print(m[2])
            if m[3] in timestamps:
                timestamps[m[3]].append(m[2])
                #print(m[3], m[2])
            else:
                timestamps[m[3]] = [m[2]]
                #print(m[3], m[2])
    
a = b = c = 0
for key in count:
    print("%-10s: %2d, %s" % (key, count[key], timestamps[key]))
    if timestamps["ACTIVE"] > timestamps["PRECHARGE"]: #line causing logic error
        a = a + 1
print(a)
```

Before getting into the calculation, I assign the timestamps with respect to the commands. This is the output for this section.

```
ACTIVE    :  3, ['0015', '0150', '0318']
WRITING   :  4, ['0030', '0200', '0447', '0503']
WRITING_A :  3, ['0100', '0345', '0430']
PRECHARGE :  2, ['0115', '0314']
REFRESH   :  1, ['0120']
```

To get `a`, the timestamps of ACTIVE must be greater than `PRECHARGE` and `WRITING` must be greater than `ACTIVE`. (Line 4, 6, 7 will contribute to the first `a` and Line 8, 9, and 12 contributes to the second `a`)

To get `b`, the timestamps of WRITING must be greater than `ACTIVE`. For the lines that contribute to a such as Line 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 12, they cannot be used to calculate `b`. So, Line 1 and 2 contribute to `b`.

To get `c`, the rest of the unused lines containing `WRITING` will contribute to `c`.

The expected output:

```
a = 2
b = 1
c = 1
```

However, in my code, when I print a, it displays 0, which shows the logic has some error. Any suggestion to amend my code to achieve the goal? I have tried for a few days and the problem is not solved yet.

Comment: There's so much going on here, it's hard to tell where to start. What do you expect `timestamps["ACTIVE"] > timestamps["PRECHARGE"]` to do? Why is the check inside the loop (which does not depend of the loop by the way)? How would you define a list of timestamps to be greater than an other list of timestamps? Have you debugged the code at all?

Comment: @hhimko, I have tried debugging, please see the code ya.

Comment: It's still not making sense, as in how do you want the comparison between two lists to work? You mentioned "greater" so first step I would do is cast those timestamps to `int()` while saving them in the list, otherwise numerical comparison is impossible. After that it's still unclear what you want to do with the list: one of the timestamps must be greater than everything in other list? `sum()` of the timestamps? First timestamp of each list? You'll need to elaborate you example on how that should work. Also I have a feeling the loop might need a tweak.

Comment: @LTJ, I did try to cast the data type to integer, but there's a syntax error. So I remove it and the error gone but it comes with logic error instead. Please, try to understand the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a function that will return the commands in order that match a pattern with gaps allowed.
I also made a more compact version of your file reading.
There is probably a better version to divide the list into two parts, the problem was to only allow elements in that match the whole pattern. In this one I iterate over the elements twice.

```
import re
commands = list()
with open ("page_stats.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.split(r"\s*\|\s*", line)
        if len(m) > 3 and re.match(r"\d+", m[1]):
            _, line, time, command, data, _ = m
            commands.append((line,time,command))

def search_pattern(pattern, iterable, key=None):
    iter = 0
    count = 0
    length = len(pattern)
    results = []
    sentinel = object()
    
    for elem in iterable:
        original_elem = elem
        if key is not None:
            elem = key(elem)
        if elem == pattern[iter]:
            iter += 1
            results.append((original_elem,sentinel))
            if iter >= length:
                iter = iter % length
                count += length
        else:
            results.append((sentinel,original_elem))

    matching = []
    nonmatching = []
    for res in results:
        first,second = res
        if count > 0:
            if second is sentinel:
                matching.append(first)
                count -= 1
            elif first is sentinel:
                nonmatching.append(second)
        else:
            value = first if second is sentinel else second
            nonmatching.append(value)
    
    return matching, nonmatching
    
pattern_a = ['PRECHARGE','ACTIVE','WRITING']
pattern_b = ['ACTIVE','WRITING']
pattern_c = ['WRITING']
matching, nonmatching = search_pattern(pattern_a, commands, key=lambda t: t[2])
a = len(matching)//len(pattern_a)
matching, nonmatching = search_pattern(pattern_b, nonmatching, key=lambda t: t[2])
b = len(matching)//len(pattern_b)
matching, nonmatching = search_pattern(pattern_c, nonmatching, key=lambda t: t[2])
c = len(matching)//len(pattern_c)

print(f'{a=}')
print(f'{b=}')
print(f'{c=}')
```

Output:

```
a=2
b=1
c=1
```